# Cypher Query - Excluding certain relationships

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I am querying my graph where it has the following nodes:

- Customer
- Account
- Fund
- Stock

With the following relationships:

- HAS (a customer HAS an account)
- PURCHASED (an account PURCHASES a fund or stock)
- HOLDS (a fund HOLDS a stock)

The query I am trying to achieve is returning all Customers that have accounts that hold Microsoft through a fund. The following is my query:

```
MATCH (c:Customer)-[h:HAS]->(a:Account)-[p:PURCHASED]-(f:Fund)-[holds:HOLDS]->(s:Stock {ticker: 'MSFT'})
WHERE exists((f)-[:HOLDS]->(s:Stock))
AND exists ((f:Fund)-[holds]->(s:Stock)) 
AND NOT exists((a:Account {account_type: 'Individual'})-[p:PURCHASED]->(s:Stock))
RETURN *
```

This almost gets me the desired results but I keep getting 2 relationships out of the Microsoft stock that is tied to an Individual account where I do not want those included.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Result:

[image]

Desired Result:

[image]

Comment: pls share the result and your expected result so that we can see what is going on.  It is hard to imagine it without data. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is duplications in your query. Lines 2 and 3 are the same. Line 2 is a subgraph of Line 1. Then you are using the variables a, p and s more than once in line 1 and line 4.  Below query is not tested but give it a try. Please tell me if it works for you or not.

```
MATCH (c:Customer)-[h:HAS]->(a:Account)-[p:PURCHASED]-(f:Fund)-[holds:HOLDS]->(s:Stock {ticker: 'MSFT'})
WHERE NOT exists((:Account{account_type: 'Individual'})-[:PURCHASED]->(:Stock))
RETURN *
```

Comment: Results are the same. At first it outputs the desired graph but after 2 seconds the 2 unwanted relationships appear. It seems weird to me that happens

Comment: what???? after 2 seconds, the result will change???

Comment: Yeah, it is very odd. Will output the desired graph and then it will add those 2 relationships. Unchecking "Connect Result Nodes" fixed this issue though.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you should just uncheck the "Connect result nodes" option in the Neo4j Browser:

[image]

Comment: This fixed it. Can you explain what this function does?

Comment: After executing the query, the neo4j browser makes another query to get the relations between the received nodes. That is why these relations in the visualization may appear a little later.